# Change the sender address

Tags: php, email

I am trying to change the from email in the script to the person who sends it so i can reply to the message sent from the form directly. at the moment when a message is sent with the form it appears to come from User@servername.com i would like to change it to the address of the person who fills the form.
I have no knowledge of php, help would be appreciated.

```
<?php    
$subject = 'Message from Website'; // Subject of your email
$to = 'me@mydomain.com';  //Recipient's E-mail
$emailTo = $_REQUEST['email'];

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.1";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1";
$headers .= "From: " . $emailTo . "\r\n"; // Sender's E-mail
$headers .= "Return-Path:". $emailTo;

$message .= 'Name : ' . $_REQUEST['name'] . "\n";
$message .= 'Email : ' . $_REQUEST['email'] . "\n";
$message .= 'Phone : ' . $_REQUEST['phone'] . "\n";
$message .= 'Message : ' . $_REQUEST['message'];

if (@mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
{
    // Transfer the value 'sent' to ajax function for showing success message.
echo 'sent';
}
else
{
// Transfer the value 'failed' to ajax function for showing error message.
echo 'failed';
}
?>
```

Comment: Why not use `Reply-to: <email>` - And pretend to send email as another user isn't gonna be a positive experience, you'll most likely get flagged as spam.

Comment: Start with the manuals http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php --- http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php

Comment: why are you using the `@` suppression operator in your call to `@mail()`?

Comment: A good library is PHPMailer though..check it out -> https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: This is the script that was with the form i only edited the Recipient's email, no idea about the @

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your headers are not being read correctly the headers require consistent usage of **\r\n** to end the header lines.  Please try the example from [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#example-3958) exactly to see if it helps you:

```
// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'To: Mary <mary@example.com>, Kelly <kelly@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Birthday Reminder <birthday@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: birthdayarchive@example.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc: birthdaycheck@example.com' . "\r\n";

// Mail it
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: I would also caution to be sure that any input from the user form be sanitized, most specifically disallowing new lines **\r** and **\n** as that would allow your spammy attacking clients to inject new headers and send out massive amounts of email that you are not aware of.